# why would shellexecute always return an error code 5?

Tags: visual-foxpro

VFP9 SP2 Really simple code running from command window. This is on my personal workstation. I am the "everything"/administrator. It does not matter if it a pdf I downloaded from the internet like a brochure or a pdf that I created. I can open the pdf by double clicking on it from file explorer.

VFP always returns error code 5.

```
DECLARE INTEGER ShellExecute IN shell32.dll ;
 INTEGER hndWin, ;
 STRING cAction, ;
 STRING cFileName, ;
 STRING cParams, ;
 STRING cDir, ;
 INTEGER nShowWin

?ShellExecute(0,"open","c:\users\jcook\desktop\TLBK460BT.pdf","","",1)`DECLARE INTEGER
```

Thanks,
John

Comment: Can you try with something other than a `.pdf`, maybe a `.txt` file?

Comment: As Stefan said, that is the "access denied" code. At that point are you executing as user jcook (or impersonating someone else)? For debugging purposes, would you temporarily comment it and try something like: FileToStr("c:\users\jcook\desktop\TLBK460BT.pdf")

Comment: Well I finally got back to this one. Cetin, I tried the FileToStr that you suggested and the error code changed to 2. I also found that in my file associates, pdf was set to be opened by Adobe Acrobat DC. I changed it to Adobe Reader 8.1 I then tried my original shellexecute and viola, it opened.

Comment: After doing some more reading it appears maybe different versions of Adobe open the files different ways. I changed by pdf's to open with Microsoft Edge and the file opens in the browser just fine from VFP.

Comment: Anyway, I have decided to go a different route. I do not want my users being taken out side my app to either a browser or Adobe readers to open a pdf. At that point they are outside my app. They could change the printer or maybe other things that may cause issues for my app. It took a LOT of research but I found an ActiveX object that lets me show a pdf from a form in my app. I have it coded, it works wonderfully and lets the user zoom, page up and down and print. It costs $600 per server but I believe it is worth it. If anyone is interested it is viscomsoft's pdfviewer activex. John

Answer (score 1):

Quoted from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-shellexecutea :

SE_ERR_ACCESSDENIED: The operating system denied access to the specified file.

So your error-codes constant could look like

```
#DEFINE SE_ERR_ACCESSDENIED 5
```

Comment: Stefan, I tried this to open a notepad file. It works perfectly. I also checked my file associations. pdf's are set to be opened with Adobe Reader DC. When I open the pdf with file explorer it opens in Adobe Acrobat Reader(64 bit). I am confused but obviously the problem has something to do with the version used to create the pdf's, maybe??? I am using xfrx to create the pdf's. Thanks, John

Comment: @vfpjohn , as Cetin said I also think it could quite likely be a shared-access conflict of two or more instances trying to open the file, or some user/process privileges conflicts.

Comment: ... or an anti-virus tool for example

Comment: _"something to do with the version used to create the pdf"_ - perhaps you could try a different or an empty PDF or a renamed txt file

Comment: ... or a crashed "invisible" Adobe reader instance

Answer (score 1):

I dealt with that issue on one client's ws using Adobe Reader as default pdf viewer -skipping the "why"-
this worked for me:

```
oshell = Createobject('wscript.shell') 
oshell.run('c:\users\jcook\desktop\TLBK460BT.pdf')
```

Update:
Try disabling "protected mode" in configuration and use shellexecuteex(): https://community.adobe.com/t5/acrobat-discussions/how-to-fix-access-denied-when-printing-pdfs-using-createprocess-without-disabling-protected-mode/m-p/12936605?profile.language=es

Comment: Hola Marco - your observation sounds interesting, will try to keep it in mind. FWIW, since your code seems to be two VFP code lines, displayed as one by the Stack Overflow implementation, perhaps the _"```-style (fenced) Markdown code blocks"_ feature could help?: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125148/implement-style-fenced-markdown-code-blocks

Comment: Hola Stefan.. - indeed it had a bad md!